# WebStorm Angular 2 live templates popup completion works wrong

Tags: webstorm, code-snippets, live-templates

I install [ng2-webstorm-snippets](https://github.com/MrZaYaC/ng2-webstorm-snippets) and when I start typing snippet code (for `example a-route-path-eager`) WebStorm overrides code completion popup by its default options

I've recorded a gif:

[image: please watch it here]

What can I do?

Comment: You can always invoke "Live Templates only" mode before typing abbreviation (by invoking `Code | Insert Live Template...` , which is `Ctrl + J` here on Windows). Current behaviour could be due to abbreviation having `-` symbols (not 100% sure but hight probability IMO).

Comment: @LazyOne you must write this as answer.  thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always invoke `Code | Insert Live Template...` (<kbd>Ctrl + J</kbd> here on Windows using Default keymap) before typing actual abbreviation (or even in process). This will list Live Templates only and nothing else (so no interference with classes/variable/etc).

Current behaviour could be due to abbreviation having `-` symbols in them which you do not type (not 100% sure but hight probability IMO).

Answer (score 0):

This most probably happens only because there is the ***appRoute*** Const (defined above) which is visible where you are trying to insert the live template.
 In other contexts, this will probably work.
Since the abbreviation of the live template is **"a-route-path-eager"** my suggestion would by to type "***a-route***" or only "***route***" instead of "**aroute**" when trying to insert the live template.